# Left-recursive error with my C grammar

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, antlr, grammar

I have a left-recursive error with my C grammar which can be found here
http://www.archive-host.com/files/1959502/24fe084677d7655eb57ba66e1864081450017dd9/cAST.txt.
When I replace

```
initializer
 : assignment_expression
 | '{' initializer_list '}'
 ;
```

with

```
initializer
 : assignment_expression
 | '{' initializer_list '}'
 |  initializer_list
 ;
```

I did this because I am trying to do this code in Ctrl-D

```
int k [2] = 1,4;
```

However this code does work with the first version

```
int k [2] = {1,4};
```

Is there a way to do without the { } please?

Comment: Are you writing a standard C grammar?! `int k [2] = 1,4;` isn't C.

Comment: Yes, but this will be the only exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this, you'd need to introduce context sensitivity (or something on that order).

The problem is that `1,4` already has a defined meaning. It's an expression using the comma operator that evaluates the `1`, discards the result, then evaluates the `4`, which is the value of the expression as a whole.

As such, to make this work, you'd have to use a different syntax for initializers than for normal expressions (and in the process, depart pretty widely from C as it's current defined). From a purely grammatical viewpoint, that almost certainly does not need to be done with context sensitivity, but it will involve basically defining the syntax for initializers separately from/in parallel with the syntax for normal expressions, instead of using a common syntax for both.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I am not really tring to depart from C, it is just that as a special case I would like the table declaration without { } to be accepted (only for the table) . Of course the one with { } must be accepted as well. Is it possible to do this without diverging from C standard ?

Comment: No, of course it's not possible because the form in question already has a defined meaning.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answers. I think I should refrain from doing that then ^^ .